# Python tkinter - auto click on selected item from Treeview

Tags: python, html, tkinter, treeview, bind

I have a treeview widget that displays a simple list from a table.
I want to automatically highlight one of the items on the list. (this works perfectly).
Now, I want this item to automatically receive a mouse click (without any action from the user). according to the documentation, use the command   `Rec_list.event_generate ('<ButtonRelease-1>' .format (button-1), when = "now")`
but without results.

```
# coding:utf-8
#version 3.x python

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk

def Load_Recette_Contenu():

    Load_Recette = tk.Toplevel()
    Load_Recette.title("Ouvrit une recette SAF")
    Load_Recette.geometry("325x178+0+0")
    Load_Recette.resizable(width=False, height=False)                                            
    # Fenêtre verrouillée
    Load_Recette.attributes("-toolwindow", 1)                                                         
    # Supprime les boutons Réduire/Agrandir
    Load_Recette.attributes("-topmost", 1)                                                             
    # au premier plan


# ==================================================
#                              TreeView
# ==================================================


# --- Insertion Table Nom HV dans TreeView
def DisplayData():
    for i in Recette_DB_BackEnd.loadRecord():
        # print("Nom de la recette --> ", i[0])
        Rec_list.insert('', 'end', text=i[0], values=(i[0]))

# --- Insertion Scrollbar
scrollbar_y = Scrollbar(Recette_TreView, orient='vertical')                                 # Ascenseur Vertical
scrollbar_y.place(x=299, y=0, height=169)


Rec_list = ttk.Treeview(Recette_TreView, selectmode="browse", columns=(1), show="headings", yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y.set) 
# --- En-tête
Rec_list.heading('#1', text="Recettes")
# --- Largeur Colonnes
Rec_list.column('#1', width=300, minwidth=40, stretch=OFF)
Rec_list.place(x=0, y=0, width=301, height=168)

scrollbar_y.config(command=Rec_list.yview)                                                       # Ascenseur Vertical

DisplayData()



def selectionItem(a):
    # === [Sélection - Widget Treeview] ===


    curItem = Rec_list.focus()
    Liste = Rec_list.item(curItem)["values"]
    # print("winfo_name()", Rec_list.winfo_name())                                            # ID widget Treeview -- Exemple : winfo_name() !treeview
    # print("Liste - TreeView - Recette sélectionnée", Liste)                                 # Affiche la sélection contenu de la liste
    # print("Liste - TreeView - Colonne Nom -->", Liste[0])
    # for child in Rec_list.get_children():                                                            # Listing du contenu de la Treeview -- Exemple : ['Recette_2020.05_8_30.5_NoName']
    #     print(Rec_list.item(child)["values"])
    # print("Rec_list.item(curItem)[","values","][0]          ", Rec_list.item(curItem)["values"][0])                                   # Affiche Nom recette depuis Treeview -- Exemple : Recette_2020.05_8_30.5_NoName
    # print("Rec_list.get_children()", Rec_list.get_children())                                                                                       # iid -- Renvoie un tuple des valeurs iid des enfants de l'élément spécifié par l'argument élément. S'il est omis, vous obtenez un tuple contenant les valeurs iid des éléments de niveau supérieur.  --- exemple : Rec_list.get_children() ('I001', 'I002', 'I003', 'I004')
    # print("Rec_list.get_children()[0]", Rec_list.get_children()[0])

    # print("Rec_list.get_children()", Rec_list.get_children([Rec_list.item(curItem)["values"][0]]))   ????????????????????

    z = -1
    for child in Rec_list.get_children():
        z = z +1
        time.sleep(1)
        Rec_list.update()
        Rec_list.selection_set(Rec_list.get_children()[z])
        # Rec_list.event_generate('<ButtonRelease-1>'.format(button-1), when="now")
        Rec_list.focus_force()
        Rec_list.focus_set()
        Rec_list.focus(Rec_list.get_children()[z])
        Rec_list.update()

    # -- Identifie le type de bouton activé --
    # un bouton pressé(event.type = 4)
    # un bouton relaché(event.type = 5)
    # un bouton pressé en mouvement(event.type = 6)
    print("\ntype :", a.type)
    # -- Identifie quel bouton pressé --
    # clic gauche(Bouton 1): event.num = 1
    # clic droit(Bouton 3): event.num = 3
    print("num :", a.num)
    # Load_Recette.update()
    # Rec_list.event_generate('<ButtonPress-1>')
    # Load_Recette.update()


# ==================================================
#                              Evénement Treeview
# ==================================================
# via souris
Rec_list.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', selectionItem)                                         # Le bouton de la souris a été relâché
```

how to activate a mouse click without user intervention?
Thank you for your time, have good day

[Auto Selection Item](https://youtu.be/V_XGwm82cJQ)

Answer (score 1):

To automate the selection I found this solution: in insert for loop where the data is from a table of a database, I use 1 particular db-data as value (better an unique id). I get the iid with get_children method using the loop index. In the for I insert data into a dictionary where the key is the iid and the value is the value (unique data) form the db.

If the goal to change data in the row and send that back into the database, you can make a query selection to find the first unchanged row, and select only the unique id, unique data of this row (or use the main autoincremented rowid). Use that id for having the iid of that row, than make focus and selection with that iid. After the binding that selection to an event you can run that calling event to run your method without clicking on any row.

```
def calling(event):
    selectedRow = tree.item(tree.focus())
    datas = selectedRow['values']
    var1 = datas[0]
    var2 = datas[1]

    yourMethod(var1, var2)


def keyGetter(val, lib):
    for key, value in lib.items():
         if val == value:
             return key
    return "key doesn't exist"

index = 0   
iidLibrary = dict()
for row in rows:
    tree.insert("", index, values = (row[0], row[1], row[2))
    iid = tree.get_children()[index]
    iidLibrary[iid] = row[3]

curs.execute(
"SELECT id_of_row FROM table WHERE something=? ORDER BY rowid ASC LIMIT 1", (variable, )
firstUnclosed = curs.fetchall()

iidActual = keyGetter(firstUnclosed[0][0], iidLibrary)
                
tree.focus(iidActual)
tree.selection_set(iidActual)

tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', calling)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly nonprofessional route, but using a library such as py-game can automatically click or select with the mouse, you would have to take in to account screen resolution though. You can also try to see if there is a property to auto-select, check the Tkinter reference guide for help, [Link 1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)

Answer (score 0):

i find solution

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import time

tree = ttk.Treeview()
for i in range(10):
    iid = tree.insert('', 'end', text=i)
tree.pack()

def event_test(iid):
    t['text'] = iid
    print("iid", iid)

def move_bottom():
    iid = tree.get_children('')[-1]
    time.sleep(1)
    if iid != tree.focus():
        iid = tree.get_children('')[5]
        tree.focus(iid)
        tree.selection_set(iid)
        print("iid", iid)

        tree.event_add('<<Declenche>>', '<ButtonRelease-1>')
        tree.after(1000, lambda: tree.event_generate('<<Declenche>>'))
        tree.bind('<<Declenche>>', event_test(iid))

t = tk.Label()
t.pack()
tk.Button(text='move', command=move_bottom).pack()

tree.mainloop()
```